# "Your command line PHP installation is too old" But it's not?

Tags: drush

I was trying to install Drush version 7.x-5.9 when it gave me the following error (whenever I try to use the drush command):

Your command line PHP installation is too old. Drush requires at     [error]
least PHP 5.3.0. To suppress this check, set the environment variable
DRUSH_NO_MIN_PHP=1

My HostMonster Info:
Apache version  2.2.26
PHP version 5.4.24
MySQL version   5.5.35-log

I've reverted back to version 7.x-5.4 of Drush and the command line is working but I would like to use the newest version if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line version of php (CLI) and the one used by your webserver (reported by hostmonster info) are not necessarily the same. Run `php -v` in a terminal to see which php command line version is installed.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! You were right. Everything is working now after I've manually set my PHP version to 5.4 in the HostMonster Control settings (it was set to 5.2 by default). Issue has been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

If you have this problem with connecting to Acquia, it's worth noting that the acquia ssh path given from their console:

```
ssh user@srv-3923.devcloud.hosting.acquia.com
```

uses a different user than the remote-user provided by the Acquia drush alias file:

```
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'root' => '/var/www/html/site.dev/docroot',
  'ac-site' => 'user',
  'ac-env' => 'dev',
  'ac-realm' => 'devcloud',
  'uri' => 'userdev.devcloud.acquia-sites.com',
  'remote-host' => 'srv-3923.devcloud.hosting.acquia.com',
  'remote-user' => 'user.dev',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%drush-script' => 'drush' . $drush_major_version,
  )
);
```

, which in our case had a different version of command-line php (3.1 vs 2.9). You can verify that this is your problem by doing a drush ssh.

To fix, we had to change the remote-user in the drush file by removing the environment extension.

```
  'remote-user' => 'user.dev',
```

to

```
  'remote-user' => 'user',
```

I do not know if there is any reason to keep the environment-specific user, but this was enough for us to pull the database through.

Comment: How is this answer related to the question?

Comment: It's a response to the more general question in the title, for users who think their version of php is correct, but are getting the same drush error. Does this warrant a separate post?